# How to do multiple page ember app?

Tags: java, ember.js, ember-data

I have multiple page app with login, users, permissions and functional area. How should structure my ember routes. Should i put all the screens in one page. which does not look ideal. 
Should i create ember routes for each page? Like for users. create/edit/delete. which looks reasonable to me. I am thinking on these lines. 
How should you transition from one page to another page. Like from users to permissions page. Should i use window.location.replace or something like that based on condition, move to another page? 
How can i pass parameters like userId, sessionId to other pages. I dont want to use get method. I can use local store but not sure whether there are better ways and what is the common practice generally followed. 
I know it depends on project to project. But would be nice to understand, what did you use?

Answer (score 0):

All of your questions are answered in the basic Ember guides: http://emberjs.com/guides/

The big advantage of Ember is that it contains a very sophisticated state engine that manages your routes for you.  Once you learn the basics of Ember, your questions will be answered.  Another hint:  stop thinking in terms of "pages" and start thinking in terms of resources, nested resources and routes.  Getting stuck on the concept of a "page" will just get in your way.